# Why Does This Firebase Query Work and The Other One Doesn't

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

When I run this query

```
self.db.collection("strokedata").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: coachid!).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, err) in
```

With these rules,

```
  rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {

       function isSignedIn() {
              return request.auth != null;
            }

          match /strokedata/{document} {

          allow write: if isSignedIn() && document == request.auth.uid;
          allow read: if document == request.auth.uid || request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid; 

          }

         match /users/{document} {

          allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
          allow read: if request.auth != null;
          allow write: if document == request.auth.uid; 
      }
    }
  }
```

The code of the uid text in the resource.data.uid turns green and the query works.

However, when I run this query

```
self.db.collection("strokedata").whereField("coachuid", isEqualTo: coachid!).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, err) in
```

With these rules, it does not work, the coachuid code does not turn green in the rules in this case.

```
  rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {

       function isSignedIn() {
              return request.auth != null;
            }

          match /strokedata/{document} {

          allow write: if isSignedIn() && document == request.auth.uid;
          allow read: if document == request.auth.uid || request.auth.uid == resource.data.coachuid; 

          }

         match /users/{document} {

          allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
          allow read: if request.auth != null;
          allow write: if document == request.auth.uid; 
      }
    }
  }
```

I have something that works, but I am curious why the coachuid query does not turn green and the rules fail each time.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please do not show pictures of code.  Copy the code into the question itself so it's easier to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Respectfully, you requested in another question that I do post images, otherwise I cannot show you that the text does not turn green for the second query.

Comment: Have now edited per your request.

Comment: You can describe what you see, or you can include both text and picture.  But pictures alone can be difficult to deal with.  Imaging if someone wanted to copy all those rules into the console to try it for themselves.  Or, consider that someone who has vision impairment can't increase the size of the font easily.

Comment: When you run app code with queries, the rendering of the rules don't change.  Are you actually saying that you use the console to test the rules using the simulator?  If so, that should be in the description of your question.  It's worth noting that the queries you show **can't** be simulated in the console.  The simulator only allows individual document get, create, update, and delete, not collection queries that could return multiple documents.

Comment: Understood, learning the ropes over here. Not sure what you mean by console testing the rules, but will look into that.